# Find the$A:=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...\frac{1}{20^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the :
>
> $$A:=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...\frac{1}{20^2}$$

---

My Try :

$$\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac{3^2+2^2}{2^2\cdot 3^2}$$

$$\frac{3^2+2^2}{2^2\cdot 3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}=\frac{(3^2+2^2)(4^2+1)}{4^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 2^2}$$

$$\frac{(3^2+2^2)(4^2+1)}{4^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 2^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}=\frac{(5^2)(3^2+2^2)(4^2+1)+(4^2)(3^2)(2^2)}{5^2 \cdot4^2\cdot3^2\cdot 2^2}$$
Now what ?

Comment: why do you need this sum?

Comment: Maxima: $$\frac{53\cdot 121915104401357}{2^8\cdot 3^4\cdot 5\cdot 7^2\cdot 11^2\cdot 13^2\cdot 17^2\cdot 19^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that the sum of the reciprocal of the squares add up to $\pi^2/6.$  So your sum equals

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 -\sum_{n=21}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

The infinite sum is less than, but very close to

$$\int_{20}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx = \frac{1}{20}.$$

So your sum is about

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 -\frac{1}{20} = 0.594934068\ldots.$$

Maple says the exact answer is $0.5961632439.$